# CS0012 The type 'XtraReport' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I recently updated my visual studio to 2017 Enterprise.
I used to use DevExpress v15.1 
Today, I upgraded my DevExpress to version 18.1 and when I build my .Net MVC5 Application Solution, I got the following error

> The type 'XtraReport' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'DevExpress.XtraReports.v15.1, Version=15.1.8.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a'.

The above Error is located in ReportController.cs

I checked my references Folder under the project to find that the DevExpress.XtraReports.v18.1 is there.

What might be the cause of this error?.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Based from the message, the XtraReport still references the older version of its DLL assembly:

```
'DevExpress.XtraReports.v15.1, Version=15.1.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a'
```

Usually this problem occurred because Project Converter failed to update `XtraReport` related references after upgrade. In this case, you can manually remove all references to older assemblies (version 15.1) and then add references to new assemblies (version 18.1).

Also make sure that web.config file has these assembly information like below example (`X` indicates revision number):

```
<add assembly="DevExpress.XtraReports.v18.1, Version=18.1.X.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
<add assembly="DevExpress.XtraReports.v18.1.Web, Version=18.1.X.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
```

If the solution above failed, try install the assemblies to the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) by navigating to `X:\Windows\assembly` (`X` stands for the system drive letter) and copy all new DevExpress assemblies to that folder (including `DevExpress.XtraReports.v18.1`), as mentioned in [this issue](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q272041/install-devexpress-assemblies-to-the-gac).

Related issues:

[Errors after upgrading DevExpress version](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T371867/errors-after-upgrading-devexpress-version-to-15-1-10-0)

[DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XtraReport is not defined after upgrade](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T425554/devexpress-xtrareports-ui-xtrareport-is-not-defined-after-upgrade-to-16-1)

[The type 'DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XtraReport' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q347301/the-type-devexpress-xtrareports-ui-xtrareport-is-defined-in-an-assembly-that-is-not)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I checked my Solution Web.Config file to find out that the assemblies are there as shown below;
`
<add assembly="DevExpress.XtraReports.v18.1, Version=18.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
<add assembly="DevExpress.XtraReports.v18.1.Web, Version=18.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
<add assembly="DevExpress.XtraReports.v18.1.Web.WebForms, Version=18.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
`